# Use if-statements when defining a constraint in Pyomo

Tags: python, constraint, pyomo

I would like to define the value of a variable `model.variable_costsPerTimeSlot [t]` in pyomo and I would like to use if-statements. Depending on the value of the if-statements, another expression should be used for assigning the value. However, I get an error message when doing this

```
Evaluating Pyomo variables in a Boolean context, e.g.
            if expression <= 5:
        is generally invalid.  If you want to obtain the Boolean value of the
        expression based on the current variable values, explicitly evaluate the
        expression using the value() function:
            if value(expression) <= 5:
        or
            if value(expression <= 5):
```

My question is how can I avoid this error? I do not really understand what the problem is. I also tried to use the value() function but I got an error telling me `NameError: name 'value' is not defined

So here you can see this constraint:

```
def costsPerTimeSlotRule (model, t):
    if (model.variable_pvGeneration [t] <= model.variable_electricalPowerTotal [t]):
        return model.variable_costsPerTimeSlot [t] == (model.variable_electricalPowerTotal [t] - model.variable_pvGeneration [t]) * SetUpScenarios.timeResolution * 60 * (model.param_electricityPrice_In_Cents[t]/3600000)
    if (model.variable_pvGeneration [t] > model.variable_electricalPowerTotal [t]):
        return model.variable_costsPerTimeSlot [t] == (model.variable_pvGeneration [t] - model.variable_electricalPowerTotal [t]) * SetUpScenarios.timeResolution * 60 * (SetUpScenarios.revenueForFeedingBackElecticityIntoTheGrid_CentsPerKWH/3600000)
model.constraint_costsPerTimeSlots = pyo.Constraint(model.set_timeslots, rule =costsPerTimeSlotRule )`
```

I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

Comment: In almost all cases you should not use an `if` statement. Typically binary variables are used. `If` is for programming, not for use in mathematical programming equations. Final advice: first write down the mathematical model on a piece of paper before starting to code.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your answer. Basically I use if many time when writing optimizaiton problems and in some cases it was also recommended to use if. For example when I want to specify a specific value in an constraint like this:
`def temperatureConstraintRule(model, t):
    if t == model.set_timeslots.first():
        return model.variable_temperature[t] ==10
    return model.variable_temperature[t] == model.variable_temperature[t-1] + ... 
model.constraint_temperature = pyo.Constraint (model.set_timeslots, rule=temperatureConstraintRule)`

Comment: There is `if(exogenous condition)` which is ok. There is `if(endogenous condition)` which is bad. It is important to understand the difference between a set/parameter and a decision variable.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your answer and effort. So I have to use a binary variable instead of the if? There is no way how to use the if with endogenous condition, right?

Comment: An endogenous `if` is almost always a bad idea as it introduces a nonlinearity that can be really difficult (discontinuous, non-differentiable).

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your answer. But I need an endogenous if in my case. I have also used endogneous if-statements several times in my models for example with a big-m approach and a binary variable. This way, the problem does not become non-linear or non-differentiable.

Comment: @PeterBe on the example constraint that you mentioned you used a KNOWN value in the if statement while in the question you are trying to use variable value to generate the constraint, it is not possible because values’ of the variables are UNKNOWN at the beginning.

Comment: I Agree with @ErwinKalvelagen about the understanding the differences between two if statements.

Comment: Thanks Oguz for your comments. Yes I understand the difference between an endogenous if-statement and an external if-statement. However, it is still possible to model endogenous if-statements for example using a big-m approach without making the problem non-linear. I was just asking, wether there is a direct way of including if-statements in Pyomo but this does not seem to be the case such that I will just use the conventional big-M approach

Comment: This will be useful https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/doc-testbuild/modeling_extensions/gdp.html

Comment: Thanks kur ag for your answer. Do I have to use Disjunction methodology of Pyomo? I do not think so. As far as I see it I can just model it with a big-M approach and an additional binary decision variable in my case. What is your take on that?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how can I avoid this error? I do not really understand
> what the problem is. I also tried to use the value() function but I
> got an error telling me `NameError: name 'value' is not defined

As stated in several comments, it seems like you're making use of endogenous `if` statements. On the other hand, if you need an exegenous `if` statement reliying on the value of an expression (after having solved a model for example), don't forget to

`from pyomo.environ import value`